# Removing the SpeechKit delay before starting recognition recording

Tags: ios, speech

I'm using `Nuance SpeechKit` in one of my apps and it seems to be working okay otherwise, but it has a short delay of approximately half a second between when I want it to record and when it actually starts recording. I'm using iOS, but the questions should be platform-independent.

[SpeechKit SDK](http://developer.nuance.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/SpeechKit_Guide/Basics.html)

[SpeechKit State Change Management](http://developer.nuance.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/SpeechKit_Guide/RecognizingSpeech.html#managing-recording-state-changes)

Any tips or tricks how to cut the delay?